# Start postgresql db every time using rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to locally start my rails server

but do I have to start my postgresql db each time I want to `rails s`?

I'm new to rails so I'm not sure how this works. I remember not having to do such a thing on something I've worked on before..

Comment: Nope. Your postgresql server just runs merrily away in the background whether or not you've started your rails server.

Comment: `rails server` command and Postgres service are not related whatsoever, but you'll need to have Postgres running if you want to use the DB from Rails, of course. You should have Postgres service start automatically with your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers you have to make sure that Postgres is runnign and serving your database. This is not handled by Rails.

Usually you would configure the Postgres server as an OS background service that starts with your system. Which operating system do you use? In case it's MacOS and you're already using Homebrew, I'd recommend using Hombrew services. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Basically you'd tell Homebrew to start postgres with your system, like this: `brew services start postgres`

Answer (score 0):

You can use system commands to run postgresql server automatically on system boot

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

or

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable
```

However it also belongs on how you install postgres